# Why is my callback function for jQuery slow() not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            posicionarBarraIdioma(); //This function aligns my div #barraIdioma at the bottom of the other div.

            $('#barraProgreso').progressbar({ value: 1 });

            $('#barraIdioma').show('fast',animarBarraProgreso);

        });

        function animarBarraProgreso() {
            $('.ui-progressbar-value').animate({width: 100 + '%'},1250, mostrarIdiomas);
        }     

        function mostrarIdiomas() {
            $('#barraProgreso').fadeOut(function() {
                $('#barraIdioma a').each(function(index, element){$(element).show()})
            });
        }
```

I need that the div #barraIdioma puts in position, then becomes visible and then the animation occurs... But when the div shows up, the animation has already run. What am I doing wrong?

---

Solved! I was accidentally hiding the progress bar along with the other div on my CSS.

Comment: does it still animate when its not in the callback for .show ?

Comment: I have tried to put the animation after the show effect, using delay or setTimeout on it, but its always the same result.
The only way I can see the animation is not hidding the div (and not using show)

Comment: Can you make a js fiddle for this?

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it. This should not be in your question body.

Answer (score 1):

I think your JavaScript is fine. I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22Fqj/) using what you had posted, and I believe it behaves in the manner you described.  Maybe the problem is elsewhere. Can you post your HTML?

The only error I noticed was, you were missing semicolons:

```
    function mostrarIdiomas() {
        $('#barraProgreso').fadeOut(function() {
            $('#barraIdioma a').each(function(index, element) {
                $(element).show(); //<-- missing semicolon here
            }); //<-- missing semicolon here
        });
    }
```